# Choose an element by distribution probability

Tags: probability-distributions

I have this probabilities:

$$P(x1) = 0.2$$ 
$$ P(x2) = 0.2$$  $$ P(x3) = 0.3$$  $$ P(x4) = 0.3$$
[Probabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHWx7.png)

My problem have dependences so, I have to put `0` at the elements that can not be selected. For example, we have to choose first $x_1$ to take $x_2$, so $x_2$ will be `0`, so my probabilities seems like:

$$ P(x1) = 0.25 $$ 
$$ P(x2) = 0 $$ 
$$ P(x3) = 0.375  $$ 
$$ P(x4) = 0.375$$

[Probabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpocE.png)

I have to choose one element, I generate a randon number between `0-1` if for example this number is `0.2` I choose $x_1$, but the problem it's how to know if I choose $x_2$ or $x_3$ because they have no range of values.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Hi !! and sorry.. I edited it, like this?

Comment: It's better, but why `x1` and not $x_1$, for instance?